# Change variable value from view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple app with controller and view (without model).
There is a variable in my Home Controller:

```
int HoursToAdd = 0;
```

I want to add or deduct 1 from it when I clicking on the button in View

```
<button onclick="">Add hour</button>
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Use javascript/jquery and ajax to call a controller method

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to store that value in DB?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to store it into db.
Can i call void methods from view? it seems i tried something like that but it didn't worked

Comment: If you are not storing it in the db, where and how are you storing it (a variable in the controller on its own wont help - the controller and there for the variable in initialized each call.

Comment: Oh, i got it, I thought that i can just create a global variable in my Controller and thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not storing it in the db, where and how are you storing it (a variable in the controller on its own wont help - the controller and there for the variable in initialized each call. – Stephen Muecke